# Puzzling differences in behavior between console and web apps

Tags: c#, .net, web

I have a piece of code in a Web API app:

```
private Stream ConvertWorkBookToStream(WorkBook workBook)
{
    var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

    // The following line throws a NullReferenceException
    workBook.write(tempFileName);

   // Remainder elided for brevity
}
```

Neither `workBook` nor `tempFileName` are `null`.

On a whim, I changed the app pool to run under a domain administrator account, to eliminate any permissions issues (since I've observed some general wonkiness on my machine of late) and re-ran it. The same exception was thrown.

Then I created a console application and copied the method, verbatim, into the app and ran it. *No exception was thrown.*

Now, it bears noting that just yesterday, I ran into a similar puzzling behavior regarding File.Exists.

Consider the following call:

```
var exists = File.Exists(@"\\myshare\\myexistingfile.ext");
```

Assuming that the path refers to a file that actually exists:

- Under a web app, `exists` returns `false` *on my machine*.
- The same operation, in a console application, returns `true`.

My coworkers are experiencing the opposite behaviors.

Can anyone explain this? I'm rather at my wits' end.

Comment: Gotta suspect some bizarre permissions issue at first blush. Assuming the web app is running under IIS, anything peculiar or unusual about the identity of the associated app pool? (eg thinking about an identity that might be prevented from traversing what it sees as a network-based resource)

Comment: What's the stacktrace? when you debug, can you see which one of them is null, if any?

Comment: @DavidW: When the app is running under IIS, the issue occurs even when the app pool is configured to run under a domain administrator account. That's why it's so darned puzzling. In theory, a console app runs under the logged on user who (theoretically) has *less* privilege than a domain administrator.

Comment: @Zohar: That's the thing: nothing I've provided is `null`. The stack trace shows that the exception is occurring deep within the internals of the `write` method (which is part of a third party tool and, unfortunately, I can't disassemble, because it wasn't shipped with debugging symbols).

Comment: I think I might fire up ProcMon and run those test apps. I bet it would give you a better picture of where it's actually cratering on the permissions side. Surely you're not being bitten by something like a snarky firewall?

Comment: @DavidW: I probably should have mentioned this, but the first error (the NullReferenceException), even occurs if the file is on the local machine. And that's what really makes me want to slam my head repeatedly against a nail board. There just doesn't seem to be any reason for it. A firewall wouldn't get in the way of local file access, would it?

Comment: @DavidW Could it have something to do with trying to access a file that *isn't* a virtual directory of the site?

Comment: If you're testing for the existence of a file via what looks like a UNC path name,eg \\share\file, then that can be interpreted as a network file request even if it is physically local to the box. That, at least theoretically, brings a nosy firewall into play.

Comment: @DavidW: Heh. In a typically epic failure to communicate, I was unclear. When I said "local" I meant "on the same physical machine." As in "C:\Temp\foo.tmp" (the value returned by Path.GetTempFileName()). :) *Surely* a firewall wouldn't get involved in that? If it does, me and that firewall are going to have some fairly explicit words.

Comment: LOL not a problem. If that path is a fully-qualified beast (**including drive letter**), then, and that same physical path is returning different values in the two environments, I can't fathom anything obvious that would explain the behavior you're seeing. When I start chasing gremlins like this that start to make me question my sanity, ProcMon becomes my friend :). You might find some bizarre access-denied ACL intervening only by virtue of the idenitity on the app pool...

Comment: One other straw grasp, @MikeHofer - is your web app rooted on a different physical drive from the console app? And is there a chance the string reference to the file *doesn't* include a drive specifier? If so, that would make the runtime resolution of FIleExists different - it would be relative to the startup folder of the app.

Comment: @DavidW Nope. Same physical drive.

Comment: Check to see if the return from Path.GetTempFileName is different from the console app and the web app.  Windows could be playing tricks with you.

Comment: @MikeHofer Darn. Worth a shot :)

Comment: @BRIAN GETS CAKE! Post an answer, dude.

Comment: ARRRRRRRRGHHHHH of course. Different temp folders for different user contexts. &)(*&(*%&*%)* :) Glad you got it solved.

Comment: @DavidW: Awww. If I were a nicer guy, I'd send you a Condolences Cupcake. But this is Cutthroat Coding. >=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the return from Path.GetTempFileName is different from the console app and the web app. Windows could be playing tricks with you.  I had similar issues attempting to write log files.  I just gave up and put them int the same directory as my web service.

Answer (score 0):

In your IIS Authentication settings, are you only having Anonymous Authentication enabled? If I remember correctly Anonymous Authentication impersonates the IUSR account with restricted privileges.

Comment: We do, actually have anonymous authentication enabled, but that's by design. It's a REST API, and our clients pass us an authentication token. All requests are anonymous and we authenticate the token with each request. Hence, we use the app pool identity. In fact, if you observe the w3wp.exe process running in the Task Manager, you can see that it's running under the domain administrator account on my local machine. (Not to say that it isn't impersonating someone else on the fly, just sayin'.)

Comment: I find it interesting that your coworkers has the opposite issue :). What account does your console application use? Also the network path \\myshare\\myexistingfile.ext, is that path located when running the cmd net use command?

Comment: It runs under my local user account. If my coworkers run the same console application, it runs under their local user account. Opposite behavior.

Comment: A thought -> Could it be that you have mounted the share under your local account, and your coworkers has not done this at all hence the opposite behavior? I'm actually just speculating as I'm not exactly sure about how windows handles the user credentials when mounting a share. Is the WebApi working when using a local path? Is your share located when running the cmd net use command?